# Convert NSObject to double

Tags: ios, swift, casting, double, nsobject

I have an array that holds the following values: [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other"]. I recognize adding the "other" makes this an NSObject array. I want to be able to retrieve the first three values as doubles when they are selected so I can multiply them with other doubles. However, when I try to do it simply, it says "Can not put binary operator * with double and NSObject". How can I typecast or convert the NSObjects to doubles?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: values [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other"] can represents pure Swift Array<Any>, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force cast using `as!`:

```
// let values = [0.1,0.2,0.3,"other"]
let val1 = values[0] as! Double
let val2 = values[1] as! Double
let val3 = values[2] as! Double
let other = values[3] as! String

print(val1 * val1)
print(val2 * val2)
print(val3 * val3)
print(other)
```

Comment: No need to be unsafe about it!

Answer (score 2):

For your `Double`s to be be stored in an array of `NSObject`s, they are converted to `NSNumber`s.

If you iterate through your array, selecting values that are `NSNumber`s using `where` and assign them to a value which is of type `AnyObject`, you can call `doubleValue` on them to retrieve the `Double` value from the `NSNumber`:

```
var myarr =  [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other"]

for d:AnyObject in myarr where d is NSNumber {
    print(d.doubleValue * 2)
}
```

**Output:**

> 0.2
>   0.4
>   0.36

---

**Explanation**:

This works because any object (an instance of a `class`) can be assigned to a value of type `AnyObject`, and when `AnyObject` is used as a concrete value, all known `@objc` properties and methods are available.  Since `NSNumber` has the `doubleValue` property, and we have already checked that `d` is an `NSNumber`, we can call `doubleValue` knowing it won't crash at runtime.

Comment: try var arr = [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other", true] Last value gives you 2.00 which seems to be wrong for me. please, see my answer.

Comment: @user3441734, that happens because `Bool` is converted to `NSNumber` as well.  It is *correct* but *unexpected*.

Comment: yes, that is i am talking about. unexpected is much better word! english is not my mother language ....

Answer (score 2):

generally the same result as vacawama's answer has, but without help of Foundation

```
var myarr: Array<Any> =  [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other", true]

for d in myarr {
    if let d = d as? Double {
        print(d)
    }
}
```

prints

```
0.1
0.2
0.18
```

if you need extracted array of doubles, you can use

```
let doubles = myarr.flatMap { $0 as? Double }
print(doubles)
```

prints

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.18]
```

declaration
`var arr: Array<Any>` or `var arr:[Any]` force your code to use pure Swift, even though you have imported Foundation before.

If you need to convert values in your array to Double values (if possible), the easiest way I can see right now (please see vacawama's notes below) is something like

```
let myarr:[Any] =  [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other", true, 17, "22.3", "-0.2e-1","27"]
let doubles = myarr.flatMap { Double("\($0)") }
print(doubles) // [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, 17.0, 22.3, -0.02, 27.0]
```

Comment: `Array<Any>` is equivalent to the preferred shorthand version: `[Any]`.

Comment: @vacawama I just added the same note :-) I prefer use Array<Any> but believe me, in reality I don't know why. You are absolutely right, apple prefer [Any]

Comment: This can give unexpected results as well.  `var myarr = [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, 17]` is an array of `Double`, but `var myarr:[Any] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, 17]` will treat the `17` as an `Int`.

Comment: 17 is Int, isn't it? I see your point of view, but ... In Swift, as 'strict type safe language', you have to tell the compiler what do you mean. Your example is interesting and the solution could be a little bit more complicated as 'one liner'. But I am sure, we can find some solution as well.

Comment: `17` is an `Int` if given no other context.  You can initialize a `Double` to `17` because `Double` implements the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol.  I was just pointing out that adding `[Any]` to the array takes an array that works as `[Double]` and turns it into an array with `Double`s and `Int`s which might be unexpected.  It could be fixed with `Double(17)` or `17.0`.

Comment: @vacawama One of solutions (it really depends on OP needs) is to convert all ' double convertible' values to Double

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast it...
The simples solution is something like:

```
let arr: [NSObject] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other"]
let result = (arr[0] as! Double) * (arr[1] as! Double)
```

But you should avoid force casting and find some better solution.

You can also `flatMap` your array and get only proper values in result like:

```
let newArr = arr.flatMap { $0 as? Double }
```

But you have to be careful with this solution as you now depend on **Foundation** and if you have a slightly different values in array eg. `[0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other", false]` you'll get a *wrong* result.

---

And adding `"other"` doesn't qualify this array to be `NSObject`. It can actually be of `Any` type as well, but this wont't change anything in case of casting values to proper types, but will add some security and will simplify things cause you won't be dependent on **Foundation**.

Comment: you can use pure Swift let arr:[Any] and let newArr = arr.flatMap{ $0 as? Double } which gives you better portability (no Foundation). try this let arr: [NSObject] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other", true] with your approach

Comment: You mean that `Bool` will be casted as well?

Comment: you are not able cast Bool as Double, and that is what we want. Bool is not a number. Swift's Bool is struct which instances are either true or false.

Comment: So what's the deal? My solution is OK 

Comment: import Foundation

let arr: [NSObject] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, "other", true]
let doubles = arr.flatMap{ $0 as? Double }
print(doubles) // [0.1, 0.2, 0.18, 1.0]  true as ? Double == nil // true!!! but you have 1.0

Comment: So the problem lays in `NSObject`... Now we're on the same page 

Comment: true is first bridged to NSNumber and than cast to Double. this is very simple example, but there are a lot 'not so easy' understandable statements, if we 'mixing' Objective-C and Swift. it could produce bug which is very hard to find (my own experience :-))

Comment: Agree on that! Mixing both can bring a lot of trouble at some point... That's why I suggested using `AnyObject` in case there are some reference types in this array 

Comment: Really!? That's a bummer! I didn't realize that. Thank you for classifications!